# how to decrypt an integer that is >26

Tags: encryption

If A=01, B=02...Z=26 and also every block consists of 2 letters, then how the number 83 will be decrypted? 
For example, 0102 (or 102) makes AB.
I suggest that 83 will be 083, where 08 is H, but I don't know how to handle the 3

Comment: also,it is the very last blockof the message, if it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A=01, B=02...Z=26
lets add 64 to every int
A=64+01, B=64+02...Z=64+26
that will give u the correspending decimal number in the ascii-table http://www.ascii-code.com/
every block consists of 2 letters, wich mean 83 is 0083,
 assuming 00 is  or (space) < > 83 would be <">

another possibility; if we only use letters, then we r sure that the max int here is 26, so 3 can be used as 30 to mark the END of the message

Comment: your second version sounds like the right one for me! thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If 00 had some meaning the number could be 0083, but it looks like your index starts with one so that would not be the case